# DISTINCT and COUNT in N:M MySQL relation

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a N:M relation that connects customers and purchase `Customer_id,Purchase_id` . I would like to know how many purchases each specific user made, from one query.

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Customer_id) AS ID,COUNT(Purchase_id) AS P FROM CustomerPruchases;
```

but it only gives me one row for the first customer in the DB. I want it for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you group then aggregate functions like `count()` apply to each group and not to the complete table

```
SELECT Customer_id as ID, 
       COUNT(Purchase_id) AS P_COUNT
FROM CustomerPruchases
group by ID
```